# Python: Connect 4

Tags: python

i need to ask the user how many rows and how many columns the user would like so my game can handle whatever sized boards but i don't know how to change my code. Here's my connect 4 code that's for a 6x7 board.

```
import random

def winner(board):
    """This function accepts the Connect 4 board as a parameter.
    If there is no winner, the function will return the empty string "".
    If the user has won, it will return 'X', and if the computer has
    won it will return 'O'."""

    # Check rows for winner
    for row in range(6):
        for col in range(3):
            if (board[row][col] == board[row][col + 1] == board[row][col + 2] ==\
                board[row][col + 3]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
                return board[row][col]

    # Check columns for winner
    for col in range(6):
        for row in range(3):
            if (board[row][col] == board[row + 1][col] == board[row + 2][col] ==\
                board[row + 3][col]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
                return board[row][col]

    # Check diagonal (top-left to bottom-right) for winner

    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(4):
            if (board[row][col] == board[row + 1][col + 1] == board[row + 2][col + 2] ==\
                board[row + 3][col + 3]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
                return board[row][col]


    # Check diagonal (bottom-left to top-right) for winner

    for row in range(5, 2, -1):
        for col in range(3):
            if (board[row][col] == board[row - 1][col + 1] == board[row - 2][col + 2] ==\
                board[row - 3][col + 3]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
                return board[row][col]

    # No winner: return the empty string
    return ""

def display_board(board):

    print "   1   2   3   4    5   6   7"
    print "1: " + board[0][0] + " | " + board[0][1] + " | " + board[0][2] + " | " + board[0][3] + " | " + board[0][4] + " | " + board[0][5] + " | " + board[0][6] + " | " + board[0][7]
    print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---"
    print "2: " + board[1][0] + " | " + board[1][1] + " | " + board[1][2] + " | " + board[1][3] + " | " + board[1][4] + " | " + board[1][5] + " | " + board [1][6] + " | " + board [1][7]
    print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
    print "3: " + board[2][0] + " | " + board[2][1] + " | " + board[2][2] + " | " + board[2][3] + " | " + board [2][4] + " | " + board [2][5] + " | " + board [2][6] + " | " + board [2][7]
    print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
    print "4: " + board[3][0] + " | " + board[3][1] + " | " + board[3][2] + " | " + board[3][3] + " | " + board [3][4] + " | " + board [3][5] + " | " + board [3][6] + " | " + board [3][7]
    print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
    print "5: " + board[4][0] + " | " + board[4][1] + " | " + board[4][2] + " | " + board[4][3] + " | " + board [4][4] + " | " + board [4][5] + " | " + board [4][6] + " | " + board [4][7]
    print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
    print "6: " + board[5][0] + " | " + board[5][1] + " | " + board[5][2] + " | " + board[5][3] + " | " + board [5][4] + " | " + board [5][5] + " | " + board [5][6] + " | " + board [5][7]
    print

def make_user_move(board):

    try:
        valid_move = False
        while not valid_move:
            col = input("What col would you like to move to (1-7):")
            for row in range (6,0,-1):
                if (1 <= row <= 6) and (1 <= col <= 7) and (board[row-1][col-1] == " "):
                    board[row-1][col-1] = 'X'
                    valid_move = True
                    break
            else:
                print "Sorry, invalid square. Please try again!\n"

    except NameError:
        print "Only numbers are allowed."

    except IndexError:
        print "You can only select columns from (1-7), and rows from (1-6)."

def make_computer_move(board):
    # Code needed here...
    valid_move = False
    while not valid_move:
        row = random.randint(0,5)
        col = random.randint(0, 6)
        for row in range (5,0,-1):
            if board[row][col] == " ":
                board[row][col] = "O"
                valid_move = True
                break

def main():
    free_cells = 42
    users_turn = True
    count = 1
    ttt_board = [ [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "," ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "] ]

    print "\nHALL OF FAME \n"

    try:
        hall_of_fame = open("HallOfFame.txt", 'r')

        for name in hall_of_fame:
            print str(count) + ".", name
            print
            count += 1

        hall_of_fame.close()

    except IOError:
        print "No Human Has Ever Beat Me.. mwah-ha-ha-ha!\n"

    choice = raw_input("Would you like to go first? (y or n): ")

    if (choice == 'y' or choice=='Y'):
        users_turn = True


    elif (choice == 'n' or choice =='N') :
        users_turn = False

    else:
        print 'invalid input'

    while not winner(ttt_board) and (free_cells > 0):
        display_board(ttt_board)
        if users_turn:
            make_user_move(ttt_board)
            users_turn = not users_turn
        else:
            make_computer_move(ttt_board)
            users_turn = not users_turn
        free_cells -= 1

    display_board(ttt_board)
    if (winner(ttt_board) == 'X'):
        print "You Won!"
        print "Your name will now be added to the Hall of Fame!"

        hall_of_fame = open("HallOfFame.txt", 'a')
        name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
        hall_of_fame.write(name+ '\n')
        print "Your name has been added to the Hall of Fame!"

        hall_of_fame.close()

        print "\nGAME OVER"
    elif (winner(ttt_board) == 'O'):
        print "The Computer Won!"
        print "\nGAME OVER"
    else:
        print "Stalemate!"
        print "\nGAME OVER \n"

#start the game

main()
```

Comment: For those still stumbling on this question and looking for a solution, here is a Connect Four game I wrote a few years ago: https://gist.github.com/poke/6934842 – It works differently to how OP does it (that’s why this is a comment, not an answer), but can handle arbitrary board sizes properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    inp = raw_input
else:
    inp = input

def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(inp(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

HEIGHT = get_int('How many rows? ')
WIDTH  = get_int('How many columns? ')
```

You can now substitute these constants in your board-extent ranges to adjust the board size.